# nginx proxy_pass with custom url

Tags: nginx

I'm deploying an angular app on a ubuntu nginx server. It's working fine with the default `location /`. In my case I'm trying to specify the location as `location /ss` and wanted to redirect to the intended page. But it in console it's trying to fetch sources from a different location(file path). Here what's working fine.

```
http://example.com:81/#/screenshots
```

with

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

But I wanted

```
http://example.com/ss
```

this to redirect to the `http://example.com:81/#/screenshots` this url. I tried

```
location /ss {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/#/screenshots;
    proxy_set_header Host localhost:8000/#/screenshots;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

But my console log says

```
GET http://example.com:81/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED
ss:44 GET http://example.com:81/view1/view1.js net::ERR_ABORTED
ss:45 GET http://example.com:81/screenshots/screenshots.js 
net::ERR_ABORTED
```

these kind of file locating problems. Is there a way to fix this in nginx conf level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/ss {
    return 301 http://example.com:81/#/screenshots;
}
```